# Updates in the DataSource reset CheckedListBox checkboxes

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, checkedlistbox

I have a CheckedListBox, binded to a BindingList:

```
private BindingList<string> list = new BindingList<string>();
public MyForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    list.Add("A");
    list.Add("B");
    list.Add("C");
    list.Add("D");

    checkedListBox.DataSource = collection;
}
```

When a certain button is clicked the list is updated:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    list.Insert(0, "Hello!");
}
```

And it works fine, the CheckedListBox is updated. However, when some of the items are checked, clicking the button not only updates the list but reset all the items to be unchecked. How can I fix that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to track check-state yourself.

As an option, you can create a model class for items containing text and check state. Then in [`ItemCheck`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.itemcheck?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) event of the control, set check state value of the item model. Also in [`ListChenged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.bindinglist-1.listchanged?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) event of your [`BindingList<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.bindinglist-1?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) refresh check-state of items.

**Example**

Create `CheckedListBoxItem` class:

```
public class CheckedListBoxItem
{
    public CheckedListBoxItem(string text)
    {
        Text = text;
    }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public CheckState CheckState { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Text;
    }
}
```

Setup the `CheckedListBox` like this:

```
private BindingList<CheckedListBoxItem> list = new BindingList<CheckedListBoxItem>();
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    list.Add(new CheckedListBoxItem("A"));
    list.Add(new CheckedListBoxItem("B"));
    list.Add(new CheckedListBoxItem("C"));
    list.Add(new CheckedListBoxItem("D"));
    checkedListBox1.DataSource = list;
    checkedListBox1.ItemCheck += CheckedListBox1_ItemCheck;
    list.ListChanged += List_ListChanged;
}
private void CheckedListBox1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
    ((CheckedListBoxItem)checkedListBox1.Items[e.Index]).CheckState = e.NewValue;
}
private void List_ListChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < checkedListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        checkedListBox1.SetItemCheckState(i,
            ((CheckedListBoxItem)checkedListBox1.Items[i]).CheckState);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! There is one issue: when the form loads, all checkboxes are unchecked. Only when I change the list the proper ones are checked.

Comment: No problem. Currently we just sync item check states when an item added/removed/edited. You can encapsulate the logic which you have in `ListChange` and put it in a method like `RefreshCheckState`, then call it after setting `DataSource`.

Answer (score 1):

Another method. It doesn't require the support of a custom class (tries not to).

Since the underlying list of items is, in this case, *unmanaged* (managed elsewhere), the checked state of the items must be handled *manually*.
It can be interesting to see what is the sequence of the events raised when an item is added or removed from the `BindingList` (e.g., there are no events that notify a list change before the list is updated, `ListChangedEventArgs.OldIndex` is never set, thus always `-1`, etc.).

Since the source of the CheckedListBox is a simple `List<string>`, when the list is updated, the Item's `CheckState` is lost. Hence, these states need to be stored an re-applied when required, calling the [SetItemCheckedState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.setitemcheckstate) method.

Since the Items' state must be adjusted to match the new list composition (after an item has beed removed or inserted) and this procedure is synchronous, the `ItemCheck` event (used to update all items `CheckState`) is raised off-beat and requires deferred execution. That's why `BeginInvoke()` is used here.

All in all, a specialized class object that stores these states internally, as shown in [Reza Aghaei's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57608351/7444103), is the way to go. Here, binding suffers from lack of support in the base classes. Not that it was anywhere stated otherwise: `CheckedListBox.DataSource` is not even browsable, for example.

```
private BindingList<string> clbItemsList = new BindingList<string>();
public MyForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    clbItemsList.Add("A");
    // (...)
    checkedListBox1.DataSource = clbItemsList;
    clbItemsList.ListChanged += this.clbListChanged;
    checkedListBox1.ItemCheck += (s, e) => { BeginInvoke(new Action(()=> CheckedStateCurrent())); };
}

private void clbListChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var item in clbCheckedItems.ToArray()) {
        if (e.ListChangedType == ListChangedType.ItemAdded) {
            checkedListBox1.SetItemCheckState(item.Index >= e.NewIndex ? item.Index + 1 : item.Index, item.State);
        }
        if (e.ListChangedType == ListChangedType.ItemDeleted) {
            if (item.Index == e.NewIndex) { 
                clbCheckedItems.Remove(item);
                continue;
            }
            checkedListBox1.SetItemCheckState(item.Index > e.NewIndex ? item.Index - 1 : item.Index, item.State);
        }
    }
}

private List<(CheckState State, int Index)> clbCheckedItems = new List<(CheckState State, int Index)>();
private void CheckedStateCurrent()
{
    clbCheckedItems = checkedListBox1.CheckedIndices.OfType<int>()
        .Select(item => (checkedListBox1.GetItemCheckState(item), item)).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! When I will be more confident with my concurrency understaning, I will try this solution. :)