# Preserve check state of the items in cascading CheckedListBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding, checkedlistbox

I have 2 `Checkedlistbox` controls in my C# windows form application program. First `Checkedlistbox` is for doctors' specialty for example dentist, radiologist and etc. If I check dentist checkbox doctors' specialty `Checkedlistbox` control, all doctors who are dentist will be shown in the doctors' name `Checkedlistbox` control.
The problem is that when I check dentist `Checkedlistbox` and then some dentists from doctors' `Checkedlistbox`, then if I check radiologist `Checkedlistbox`, then doctors' name `Checkedlistbox` will be reset and all my dentist checked checkbox will be de-selected.
What I have tried:
Doctors' name `Checkedlistbox` data source:

```
DoctorsIDCheckedlistbox.DataSource = _ClinicEntities.Tbl_Doctors
      .Where(w => _SelectedSpecialty.Contains(w.SpecialtyID))
      .Select(s => new DoctorListCheckbox{ Name = s.Name + " " + s.LastName, DoctorID = s.DoctorID })
      .ToList();

DoctorsIDCheckedlistbox.DisplayMember = "Name";
DoctorsIDCheckedlistbox.ValueMember = "DoctorID";
```

Then I save checked items in `ItemCheck` event:

```
private void DoctorsID_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
    int doctorID = Convert.ToInt32(DoctorsIDCheckedlistbox.SelectedValue);
    if (e.NewValue == CheckState.Checked)
    {
        _SelectedDoctorsChecked.Add(doctorID.ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        _SelectedDoctorsChecked.Remove(doctorID.ToString());
    }
}
```

Then for doctors' specialty `ItemCheck` event:

```
private void SpecialtyTypeID_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < DoctorsIDCheckedlistbox.Items.Count; i++)
    {
         if (_SelectedDoctorsChecked.Contains(DoctorsIDCheckedlistbox.Items[i].ToString()))
         {
             try
             {
                 DoctorsIDCheckedlistbox.SetItemChecked(i, true);
             }
             catch (Exception ex)
             {
                 MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
             }
        }
    }
}
```

I expect code above look through `_SelectedDoctorsChecked` list which is selected doctors and check them when doctors' specialty checkboxes status changes. But it don't work.

Example:
I check A in doctors' specialty and items 1, 2 and 3 will be shown in doctors' name. I check 1 and 3. When I check B in doctors' specialty, Items 1, 2 and 3 from A and 4, 5 and 6 from B will be shown. I expect number 1 and 3 be checked. But it won't.

**Edit:**
My `Checkedlistbox` control data source:

```
DoctorsIDCheckedlistbox.DataSource = _ClinicEntities.Tbl_Doctors
   .Where(w => _SelectedSpecialty.Contains(w.SpecialtyID))
   .Select(s => new DoctorListCheckbox{ Name = s.Name + " " + s.LastName, DoctorID = s.DoctorID })
   .ToList();

   DoctorsIDCheckedlistbox.DisplayMember = "Name";
   DoctorsIDCheckedlistbox.ValueMember = "DoctorID";
```

And `DoctorListCheckbox` class:

```
 public partial class DoctorListCheckbox
 {
    public int DoctorID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public CheckState CheckState { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
 }
```

I have did it based on [Microsoft Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-determine-checked-items-in-the-windows-forms-checkedlistbox-control)

Comment: Is the Remove() causing the issue?

Comment: @jdweng, I don't think so. I have debugged my program. All items in the `_SelectedDoctorsChecked` are the ones I have selected. It is correct. I think there is problem with `_SelectedDoctorsChecked.Contains(DoctorsIDCheckedlistbox.Items[i].ToString())` line. But I couldn't find the problem.

Comment: To help debug make DoctorsIDCheckedlistbox.Items[i].ToString() a variable like string doctorName = DoctorsIDCheckedlistbox.Items[i].ToString();   Then check the value to  see if it is correct.

Comment: It gives me: `"EF.DoctorList"` for all `DoctorsIDCheckedlistbox.Items[i].ToString()`.

Comment: Then you added to the box "EF.DoctorList" for every value.

Comment: Why wouldn't you simply store selected items  in a collection on each ItemCheck event and then select them when you change data source?

Comment: [Updates in the DataSource reset CheckedListBox checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57607243/3110834)

Comment: @RezaAghaei, It doesn't work. I have updated my question based on your answer. Can you please take a look at that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basics are same as what I explained in [Updates in the DataSource reset CheckedListBox checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57608351/3110834).

You need to define a `BindingList<Specialties>` as data source of the specialties checked list box and show all specialties.

For doctors, you need an empty `BindingList<CheckedListBoxItem<Doctor>>` and set it as data source of doctors checked list box. Then you need to handle the following events:

- `ItemChecked` event of specialties checked list box: If the item is checked, then find all doctors with the checked specialty from your repository and them as `CheckedListBoxItem<Doctor>` to the binding list. Otherwise, find all doctors with unchecked specialty in the binding source and remove them.
- `ItemChecked` event of doctors: Sync check state of the binding list item using the check state of checked list box item.
- `ListChanged` event of the binding list: Sync the checked list box items check states, using the check state of the binding list items.

### Example

Here is the full example for a scenario of having 2 checked list box of specialties and doctors and select doctors based on the selected specialties:

**Models**

```
public class Speciality
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public override string ToString() { return Name; }
}
public class Doctor
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int SpecialityId { get; set; }
    public override string ToString() { return Name; }
}
public class CheckedListBoxItem<T>
{
    public CheckedListBoxItem(T item)
    {
        DataBoundItem = item;
    }
    public T DataBoundItem { get; set; }
    public CheckState CheckState { get; set; }
    public override string ToString() { return DataBoundItem.ToString(); }
}
```

**Sample Data**

```
public class DB
{
    public IEnumerable<Speciality> Specialities
    {
        get
        {
            return new List<Speciality>()
            {
                new Speciality(){ Id= 1, Name ="S1"},
                new Speciality(){ Id= 2, Name ="S2"},
                new Speciality(){ Id= 3, Name ="S3"},
            };
        }
    }
    public IEnumerable<Doctor> Doctors
    {
        get
        {
            return new List<Doctor>()
            {
                new Doctor(){ Id= 1, Name ="D1", SpecialityId = 1},
                new Doctor(){ Id= 2, Name ="D2", SpecialityId = 2},
                new Doctor(){ Id= 3, Name ="D3", SpecialityId = 2},
                new Doctor(){ Id= 4, Name ="D4", SpecialityId = 3},
                new Doctor(){ Id= 5, Name ="D5", SpecialityId = 3},
                new Doctor(){ Id= 6, Name ="D6", SpecialityId = 3},
            };
        }
    }
}
```

**Form Event Handlers**

```
DB db = new DB();
BindingList<Speciality> specialities;
BindingList<CheckedListBoxItem<Doctor>> doctors;
private void Form10_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    specialities = new BindingList<Speciality>(db.Specialities.ToList());
    specialitiesCheckedListBox.DataSource = specialities;
    doctors = new BindingList<CheckedListBoxItem<Doctor>>();
    doctorsCheckedListBox.DataSource = doctors;
    doctors.ListChanged += doctors_ListChanged;
}
private void doctors_ListChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < doctorsCheckedListBox.Items.Count; i++) {
        doctorsCheckedListBox.SetItemCheckState(i,
            ((CheckedListBoxItem<Doctor>)doctorsCheckedListBox.Items[i]).CheckState);
    }
}
private void specialitiesCheckedListBox_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
    var item = (Speciality)specialitiesCheckedListBox.Items[e.Index];
    if (e.NewValue == CheckState.Checked) {
        db.Doctors.Where(x => x.SpecialityId == item.Id)
            .Select(x => new CheckedListBoxItem<Doctor>(x)).ToList()
            .ForEach(x => doctors.Add(x));
    }
    else {
        doctors.Where(x => x.DataBoundItem.SpecialityId == item.Id)
            .ToList().ForEach(x => doctors.Remove(x));
    }
}
private void doctorsCheckedListBox_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
    ((CheckedListBoxItem<Doctor>)doctorsCheckedListBox.Items[e.Index])
        .CheckState = e.NewValue;
}
```

Comment: Great thanks for your help. It is working perfect. Do you mind if I ask a related question about searching through list?

Comment: You're welcome. If the new question may need some piece of code, it's better to ask a new question in a separate post; however if you think it's something that I may be able to answer in the comments, feel free to ask in the comments. In case you asked a the question in a new post, feel free to let me know about your new question, I'll take a look at that.

Comment: Your kindness sir. Sorry for my delay, I had to get to work to access related codes. I have posted a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59232592/save-checkbox-status-when-searching-through-checkedlistbox-control-in-c-sharp-wi